# Drawing a new System.Drawing.Bitmap

Tags: .net, linqpad

This code generates an exception with the latest LINQPad 4.28 beta

```
new System.Drawing.Bitmap(200, 200).Dump();
```

Is this a problem in my code or a problem with LINQPad's .Dump() extension method?

Comment: In 4.26.2, I don't get an exception, but I don't get an image either.  (I just see the properties)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Being able to dump bitmaps is a new feature of the LINQPad 4.28 beta - but it seems there's a bug. I'll upload a fix later today.

Edit: The new build has now been uploaded. You can test it by running this:

```
using (var b = new System.Drawing.Bitmap (400, 200))
using (var g = Graphics.FromImage (b))
using (var f = new Font ("Arial", 40))
{
    g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
    g.FillEllipse (Brushes.CadetBlue, 0, 0, 400, 200);
    g.DrawString ("LINQPad", f, Brushes.Black, 75, 70);
    b.Dump();
}
```

Note that you can also dump images by calling **Util.Image**, passing in a filename or URI. You can use the latter to draw graphs using [Google's Chart API](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/); for example, the following:

```
Util.Image ("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=p3&chd=s:Uf9a&chs=350x140&chl=January|February|March|April")
```

generates this output:

[image: Google Chart Demo]

Comment: Thanks Joe! I'll try it out this evening.

Comment: In 4.43.06 I needed to do: Util.Image("url").Dump()

Comment: @Tim: not will not need to write .Dump() if you have LinqPad in "C# Expression" mode. (old comment, I know :) )

Answer (score 4):

LINQPad cannot draw bitmaps using Dump().

Instead, you can write

```
Application.Run(new Form { ClientSize = bitmap.Size, BackgroundImage = bitmap});
```

Comment: Actually, SLaks, in the latest version it can ;-)
Thanks for the workaround anyway :-)